# When trying to deploy my web api from Bitbucket to Aws docker it gives invalid argument error and build fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, bitbucket, amazon-ecs, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to add a production environment in AWS using bitbucket:

First I have created a new repository in Bitbucket and committed all code to this repository.

After that I have created a new code build in AWS and linked that to the bitbucket repository and started the build process, but it fails every time. I have also changed buildspec.yml file but still the build process failed.

[image]

Comment: It looks like only the tag of the docker image is set. Try to set the docker repository name too.

Comment: from the error it looks like you dont have `AWS_REGISTRY_URL` set, that's why the tag results in `:master_hash` which is invalid. Double-check where you are setting `AWS_REGISTRY_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using the following command

```
docker build -t <IMAGE_NAME> .
```